# javascript closure example

Tags: javascript

I was reading this website for notes on closure:  blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html

It had the following example:

```
function buildList(list) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = 'item' + list[i];
    result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
  }
  return result;
}

function testList() {
  var fnlist = buildList([1,2,3]);
  // using j only to help prevent confusion - could use i
  for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
    fnlist[j]();
  }
}
```

Their notes (correctly) point out:

> The line result.push( function()
>   {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} adds a
>   reference to an anonymous function
>   three times to the result array. If
>   you are not so familiar with anonymous
>   functions think of it like:
>       pointer = function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])};
>       result.push(pointer);
>
> Note that when you run the example,
>   "item3 undefined" is alerted three
>   times! This is because just like
>   previous examples, there is only one
>   closure for the local variables for
>   buildList. When the anonymous
>   functions are called on the line
>   fnlistj; they all use the same
>   single closure, and they use the
>   current value for i and item within
>   that one closure (where i has a value
>   of 3 because the loop had completed,
>   and item has a value of 'item3').

Is there a "correct" way to get the "expected" behavior in javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: btw, this has nothing to do with jquery (per your question title), just plain old javascript

Comment: @Matt -- agreed.  Just had jquery on the mind.  Title now edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result.push((function (jtem, j) {
   return function() { alert(jtem + ' ' + list[j]); }
})(item, i));
```

You create an anonymous function which introduces a new variable scope. You immediately execute that function, passing your variables, which become the new variables `jtem` and `j` in a new scope, hence the "connection" to `item` and `i` is "broken". You then return the actual function, which now uses different variables (you could keep the names `i` and `item`, I just changed them for illustrative purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you assign the value of i to a another variable so that variable can be part of the closure.

```
function buildList(list) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = 'item' + list[i];
    result.push(function(cItem, index){ 
       return function(){ alert(cItem + ' ' + list[index]); }
    }(item, i));
  }
  return result;
}
```

The reason for this is that JavaScript does not have block scope, but a lexical scope that is capture by functions.  To get around this problem, you create another function, as seen above, thereby capturing the variables into a new scope that will not be affected by the loop.

Comment: Actually -- when I try this I actually get "item3 3" in the alert box three times.   I would hope to be able to see "item1 1" "item2 2" "item3 3"

Comment: This has the exact same effect as the original, you're just moving the "problem" to another variable.